# customizing QlineEdit in Qt

Tags: qt, qlineedit

I am making a name field using QlineEdit. I want the entry in this field is entered such that the first character of every word is always uppercase. I don't know how to set the inputmask for that, could anyone please help me out..
thnx in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just a quick solution which I came up with and there are better solutions of course (Implementing your own line edit for example), but this works as I tested.

This is a **SLOT**:

```
void main_window::on_line_edit_0_text_changed( QString text )
{
    QString tmp = text;

    tmp.truncate( 1 ); // tmp is now first char of your text
    tmp = tmp.toUpper();

    if( text.size() > 1 )
    {
        text.remove( 0, 1 );
        text = text.toLower();
        text.prepend( tmp );
        line_edit_0->setText( text );
    }
    else
    {
        line_edit_0->setText( tmp );
    }
}
```

The **connect**:

```
connect( line_edit_0, SIGNAL( textChanged( QString ) ), this, SLOT( on_line_edit_0_text_changed( QString ) ) );
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about the `inputMask`, but you can do it by subclassing [QValidator](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qvalidator.html), or you can use [QRegExpValidator](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qregexpvalidator.html).

Comment: Yep, subclass QValidator and reimplement QValidator::fixup(), I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass QLineEdit and override `keyPressEvent`. QValidator is primarily for forbidding bad inputs as opposed to generating good ones, but for this simple case, `fixup` will probably do.